# post as a FB-page does not work

Tags: facebook, api, post, sdk

i use the wordpress social login plugin to log in on my page. it works also to log in with a fb-page but if i want to share (as user it works fine) it does not work
i load the SDK Asynchronously and use JS SDK to post like:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {
            link: MYLINK
        }, function(response) {
            if (!response || response.error) {
               jQuery('#warning').html(errorwarning);
            }
        else {
           alert('response.id')
        }
    else
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

I get the id of the post as respone, but there is no post on the FB-pages wall
Loged in as user it works.
I added these permissions: publish_stream, manage_pages and offline_access.

Answer (score 0):

you must use your page ID instead of me

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        FB.api('/'+page_id+'/feed', 'post', {
            link: MYLINK
        }, function(response) {
            if (!response || response.error) {
               jQuery('#warning').html(errorwarning);
            }
        else {
           alert('response.id')
        }
    else
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: thx for the question, but it should work with "/me" anywhay. i tried also with the page-id, its the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

your answer will only let the user post to the FB page as 'user' not as 'page'.

I think the question is "How to post as PAGE"